# How can I solve this MINLP problem using Mosek solver? Realize with matlab

Tags: matlab, solver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvYrY.png)

i want to solve this problem by the MOSEK solver，but isn't work.

```
x_num = 36;  
xd = rand * 3000;  
yd = rand * 3000; 
x = initialize_user(x_num);
M = 1e9;
u = zeros(x_num,1);
for i =1:x_num
    if ((x(i,1)-xd)^2+(x(i,2)-yd)^2) <= R1^2
    u(i) = 1;
    end 
end

R1 = 100;  
M = 1e9;  

clear prob;
num_variables = 2 + x_num;  
prob.c = [0, 0, u'];  

num_constraints = x_num;
prob.a = zeros(num_constraints, num_variables);

for i = 1:x_num
  
    prob.a(i, 2+i) = 1;  
    prob.a(i, 1) = -2 * x(i, 1);  
    prob.a(i, 2) = -2 * x(i, 2); 
    prob.a(i, 3+x_num+i) = -1; 
    prob.buc(i) = -R1^2 - M;
end


prob.blx = [0; 0; zeros(x_num, 1)];  
prob.bux = [3000; 30000; ones(x_num, 1)]; 


clear param;
param.MSK_IPAR_INTPNT_MAX_ITERATIONS = 200; 
[r, res] = mosekopt('maximize', prob, param);
```

*** Error(1200): prob.c has wrong length

Mosek error: MSK_RES_ERR_IN_ARGUMENT (A function argument is incorrect.)

There may be a problem with the definition of prob, but I don’t know how to modify it. Please help me solve this problem, or give me some suggestions

There may be a problem with the definition of prob, but I don’t know how to modify it. Please help me solve this problem, or give me some suggestions

Comment: Here ``prob.a(i, 3+x_num+i) = -1; `` it clearly looks that you will have more than ``2+x_num`` columns in ``a``, so the dimensions of ``a`` and ``c`` are incompatible.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to model the problem from the image, then your model is completely wrong. The issue is not with your Mosek code, but rather that you misunderstand how such a model is supposed to look in general. Maybe start learning with easier models and easier  modeling tools such as YALMIP. You will also find almost identical models on the Mosek google group https://groups.google.com/g/mosek/c/UIbNfgGIXyc/m/sj4Gi3rPDwAJ